# Where is the library of Caffe in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, caffe

I am trying to get its path in Ubuntu 16.04 but can't find it by dpkg -l | grep lib. Only irrelevant stuff showed up in the search result.
It should be a .so file.
Any idea to get it? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Caffe Deep learning framework is not installed on Ubuntu by default. You can install it by following the instructions mentioned on their [official website](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/install_apt.html).

This is Caffe version 1. Confirm the version you need first. Caffe v2 is available [here](https://caffe2.ai/docs/getting-started.html?platform=ubuntu&configuration=prebuilt).

Comment: Actually my platform is g3.4xlarge instance with Deep Learning AMI in which both caffe 1 & 2 are preinstalled but can't find any .so file in usr/local/lib. The one I need is  version 1. Any command can search it?

Comment: try (in bash) `find / -name "libcaffe.so"` @Anndexi9

Comment: @Anndexi9 I'm not very familiar with DL AMI but looking at their docs, it looks like you could use Caffe by activating a virtual environment.
`source activate caffe_pxx` (replace xx according to Python version).
Source: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/get-started-with-deep-learning-using-the-aws-deep-learning-ami/